# Convert the PDE into divergence form

Tags: partial-differential-equations, matlab

I'm trying to use MATLAB's PDE solver to solve the following PDE

$$
(-Lx + \gamma y^2 - F)u_x +(-Sy - \gamma xy)u_y + \sigma^2 u_{yy} = -1
$$

$$
L, \gamma, F, S, \sigma^2 \in R
$$

I need to put this into divergence form to use with MATLAB's solver

$$
-\nabla \cdot(c \nabla u)+a u=f
$$

a, c, and f are functions of position (x, y) and possibly of the solution u.

If we write

$$
c=\left(\begin{array}{ll}
c_1 & c_3 \\
c_2 & c_4
\end{array}\right)
$$

then,

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \nabla \cdot(c \nabla u)=c_1 u_{x x}+\left(c_2+c_3\right) u_{x y}+c_4 u_{y y} \\
& +\left(\frac{\partial c_1}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial c_2}{\partial y}\right) u_x+\left(\frac{\partial c_3}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial c_4}{\partial y}\right) u_y
\end{aligned}
$$

Therefore $c_1 = 0, \quad c_4 = \sigma^2$

$c_2 = -Lxy + \gamma y^3/3 - F + K_2(x)$

$c_3 = -Sxy - \gamma yx^2/2 + K_3(y)$

However, this won't satisfy the constraint of $c_2 + c_3 = 0$

My expertise isn't in PDE's. Is there a trick in converting this into the required form. Or alternatively, is there a better way to solve this.

Thanks in advance.